# Tmux equivalent of GNU screen's "c" command in copy mode?

Tags: tmux

GNU screen's copy mode has a `c` command to mark the left margin which is very useful when you want to copy multi lines but ignore some leading white spaces. For example, with the following lines —

```
123456789

    A line
    B line
    C line

123456789
```

I want to copy `A line` to `C line` but I don't want the leading spaces. With GNU screen I'd do like this:

1. Press `<c-a> [` to enter copy mode.
2. Move cursor to `A` (column 5) and press `c`. This tells screen's copy mode to ignore chars before column 5.
3. Press `<space>` to mark the beginning of the text.
4. Move cursor to end of `C line`.
5. Press `<space>` to mark the end of the text and at the same time put the copied text to screen's buffer.

Does tmux has similar functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out what I'm looking for is tmux's `rectangle mode`.

From `man tmux` —

```
The following commands are supported in copy mode:

    Command               vi      emacs

    ... ...

    rectangle-on
    rectangle-off
    rectangle-toggle      v       R

    ... ...
```